# Getting rid of 3d look of MDI frame window

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have an MFC MDI application and I'd like to get rid of the (now somewhat outdated) 3d look.

**Original 3d look:**

[image]

**The look I want:**

[image]

I've managed to do this by overloading the `CMDIFrameWnd::CreateClient` virtual method of my CMDIFrameWnd derived class and replacing `dwExStyle = WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;` with `dwExStyle = 0;`at some point.

This works, but each time the document window passes from the maximized state to the tiled state and one some other occasions, the `CMDIChildWnd::UpdateClientEdge` function is called and that function modifies the style back to `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` thus reverting back to the 3d rectangle. Unfortunately the `UpdateClientEdge` method is not virtual, therefore if I overload it, the original `CMDIChildWnd::UpdateClientEdge` gets called instead of my overloaded `CMyMDICHildWnd::UpdateClientEdge`.

Both `CMDIChildWnd::UpdateClientEdng` and `CMDIChildWnd::CreateClient`functions are located in winmdi.cpp.

So I'm stuck here. Does anybody have an idea how this could be achievd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UpdateClientEdge` contains the following code:

```
BOOL bIsTabbedMDIChild = pChild != NULL && pChild->IsTabbedMDIChild();
if ((pChild == NULL || pChild == this) && !bIsTabbedMDIChild)
{
    //change the border
}
```

`IsTabbedMDIChild` is virtual so you return `TRUE` for `IsTabbedMDIChild` to fool `UpdateClientEdge` and stop it from making changes.

```
BOOL CMyMDIChildWnd::IsTabbedMDIChild() { return TRUE; }
```

(as far as I can tell `IsTabbedMDIChild` is not used anywhere else)

Comment: I like this answer better than mine :) I too couldn't find any references to that mysterious `IsTabbedMDIChild` other than from `UpdateClientEdge`.

Comment: ++8 hours later google still returns no hits for `IsTabbedMDIChild` ;-) Hack'ish, but neat.

Comment: Actually  overriding `IsTabbedMDIChild` is n ot quite enough because `CMDIChildWnd::UpdateClientEdge` is also called from `CMDIChildWnd::OnDestroy()` and as there is no more child window, the evaluation of `bIsTabbedMDIChild` in `if ((pChild == NULL || pChild == this) && !bIsTabbedMDIChild)` is shortcircuited. Therefore an `ON_WM_DESTROY()` handler must be implemented in `CMyMDIChildWnd` and `CFrameWnd::OnDestroy();` should be called there instead of `CMDIChildWnd::OnDestroy();`.

Answer (score 3):

This `CMDIChildWnd::UpdateClientEdge()`, according to my search through the MFC source directory, is only called from three places:

- CMDIChildWnd::OnMDIActivate()
- CMDIChildWnd::OnWindowPosChanging()
- CMDIChildWnd::OnDestroy()

All three are handlers of Windows messages `WM_MDIACTIVATE`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and `WM_DESTROY`. I would create handlers for these messages and clone the MFC code minus the call to `CMDIChildWnd::UpdateClientEdge()`.

I agree, it's ugly, But no more that forcing that `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` style on people...

Comment: Thought about something like that too, really ugly. MFC should provide proper functions for choosing such things. Maybe they will come up with this in one or two years ;-).